# $p$-adic norm of conjugates of an algebraic number

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic number in an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n$ be its conjugates (so $\alpha_1=\alpha$).

Do we have $|\alpha_i|_p = |\alpha_j |_p$ for $i \neq j$ or not?

Comment: Do you mean algebraic over $\mathbf Q$ or over $\mathbf Q_p$? The term "algebraic number" on its own ordinarily means algebraic over $\mathbf Q$, and if that is what you meant then the answer to your question is (generally) *no*. For instance, the polynomial $x^3 - x + 10$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ but over $\mathbf Q_2$ it is reducible with one root in $\mathbf Q_2$ of absolute value $1/2$ and two roots of degree $2$ over $\mathbf Q_2$ each with $2$-adic absolute value $1$. In the answer by Robert Green, the norm means norm down to $\mathbf Q_p$, not down to $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: I meant algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user48900 Oh, moreover now it appears magically to be included inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Nice. Have you heard about the word "hypothesis". For instance, if I ask you "is this differentiable ?" without saying more, you won't go far in trying to answer to me. Anyway.

Comment: The $p$-adic absolute value $| |_p$ has a unique extension from $\mathbf Q_p$ to any finite extension, so I do not think there is any ambiguity about what that absolute value notation could mean. The true source of ambiguity, which is I suspected the OP was not fully aware of, and hence the question in my initial comment, is that speaking about $|\alpha|_p$ for an algebraic number $\alpha$ is often ambiguous since it can depend on *how* $\alpha$ is embedded into a $p$-adic field. The issue is that $\mathbf Q$-conjugacy and $\mathbf Q_p$-conjugacy are not always the same thing.

Comment: @user48900, you can *not* use the $p$-adic absolute value "freely" on algebraic numbers in the way I suspect you are thinking. Even though the $p$-adic absolute value on $\mathbf Q_p$ is unambiguous, an abstract number field might have several different embeddings into $\mathbf Q_p$ and changing the embedding can change the $p$-adic absolute value of the same number. For instance, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$ can be viewed in $\mathbf Q_7$, but depending on which square root in $\mathbf Q_7$ you mean by $\sqrt{2}$, one of $|3+\sqrt{2}|_7$ or $|3-\sqrt{2}|_7$ is  $1/7$ and the other is $1$.

Comment: @KCd: Ok, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if it is an algbraic number over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $N$ be the norm of the extension (of your $p$-adic field) generated by $\alpha$. then $|\alpha|_p = {}^{d}\sqrt{|N(\alpha)}|_p$ were  $d$ is the degree of the extension. And as $N(\alpha)$ is equal to the product of the conjugates of $\alpha$, the result follows. See for instance [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Turner.pdf) for details.

No if it is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}_p$. (Leave this as an exercise to you.) You will please remark that if $\alpha = \sqrt{7}$ and $p=5$, you will never be able to inject $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ in $\mathbb{Q}_5$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user48900 you are welcome.

Comment: @RobertGreen, your $p$-adic example is not ideal because it doesn't address the main point that $\mathbf Q$-conjugate elements in $\mathbf Q_p$, or more generally in a field extension of $\mathbf Q_p$, need not have the same $p$-adic absolute value: the two roots of your polynomial $x^2-7$ both have $5$-adic absolute value $1$ in the extension they generate. A better example, entirely inside $\mathbf Q_5$, is $1 \pm 2i$. Depending on which square root of $-1$ in $\mathbf Q_5$ you call $i$, one of $1 \pm 2i$ will have $5$-adic absolute value $1/5$ and one will have $5$-adic absolute value $1$.

Comment: @KCd The point of this example (a remark, as I wrote) was not to address the question, but to show to the OP that not every algebraic extension of $\mathbf Q$ is injectable in every $\mathbf Q_p$.

Comment: @RobertGreen, fair enough, but even if you granted the OP knowledge of finite extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$, thereby rendering the "problem" of no embeddings moot, the ambiguity of the notation $|\alpha|_p$ for an abstract algebraic number $\alpha$ still remains and I think this is very important for someone learning this stuff to realize.